# MATLAB: What is the difference between pzmap and pzplot?

Tags: matlab

What is the difference between ***pzmap*** and ***pzplot*** ?? *Both are used to plot the poles and zeros of the LTI system.*

For example:

Lets say I define my *transfer function* via **tf** *command*:

`t = tf([2 5],[1 3 2])`

[Transfer Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THG8X.png)

***Continuous-time transfer function.***

But when I try to plot the zero-pole-map via *pzmap*, I got:

`pzmap(t)`

And with *pzplot*, I got the same plot:

`pzplot(t)`

[Plot with **pzmap** and **pzplot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/763ZU.jpg)

Both are the same plots. What is the difference then between **pzmap** and **pzplot** ??

Comment: There is no difference. [`pzplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pzplot.html) allows for customization of the plot, and returns a handle to the plot object. [`pzmap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pzmap.html) only returns the poles and zeros. This can be gleaned by reading the documentation for both functions, and it is explicit in the documentation of `pzmap`: "For additional options for customizing the appearance of the pole-zero plot, use `pzplot`."

Comment: So there's at least one difference. Maybe it's not useful in most cases but when you want to customize the plot there's a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pzplot` allows you to customize your figure. For example, the marker size or line width. An example of how to customize your figure:

```
close all;clear;clc;

Ts = 1;
num = [1, 0.5, 0, 1]; % b
den = [0, 3, 2, 0]; % a
HZ = tf(num, den, Ts, 'variable', 'z^-1');

pzplot(HZ)
h = findobj(gca, 'type', 'line');
set(h, 'markersize', 9)
text(real(roots(num)) - 0.1, imag(roots(num)) + 0.1, 'Zero')
text(real(roots(den)) - 0.1, imag(roots(den)) + 0.1, 'Pole')
axis equal
```

However; `pzmap` command only maps the locations of zeros and poles.

[image: markersize]

**Notice here that marker sizes are larger than default size set by MATLAB.**